# Reference autobahn twisted sendmessage from another class not working

Tags: python, twisted, autobahn

I am trying to use the sendMessage function provided by WebSocketServerProtocol in a seperate file/class but getting exceptions.

```
class MyServerProtocol(WebSocketServerProtocol):
    def onMessage(self, payload, isBinary):

    #input = payload
    #print payload

    # echo back message verbatim
    #self.sendMessage(payload, isBinary)

    cg = coreg.DataGatherCg
    cg.test(cg())
```

in coreg:

```
from appserver import MyServerProtocol
from autobahn.twisted.websocket import WebSocketServerProtocol, \
    WebSocketServerFactory

class DataGatherCg(MyServerProtocol):
    def test(self):
        MyServerProtocol.send(self,'test',False)
```

I am getting the error:

```
(<type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>): 'DataGatherCg' object has no attribute 'state')
```

I am trying to put it in a seperate file and class as the class will eventually be huge and I would prefer to have them separate so I can keep track of everything.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

UPDATE:  Can someone provide an example of how to "...split a class due to complexity, create a mix-in class and inherit from it."

Comment: Basically you can do such cross class calls in Python, but you don't do that. It create spaghetti code. If you have to split a class due to complexity, create a mix-in class and inherit from it.

Comment: can you provide an example of how to do this?  I have not done a mix-in class before.